# how to get one column data from one table into another table as different columns in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a data in a table called

```
unsorted
```

---

```
Scott
100
10
Miller
200
20
Mike
300
30
Allen
400
4
```

Now, I want the above data in another table sorted with 3 columns

```
name   sal   deptno
```

---

```
Scott  100   10
Miller 200   20
Mike   300   30
Allen  400   40
```

I am processing a PL/SQL query but to retrieve I want to give in each column

I tried with different methodologies but showing some errors.

```
DECLARE 
  CURSOR raw_cur IS 
     SELECT raw_data 
       from table_a; 
  raw_rec raw_cur%ROWTYPE; 
BEGIN 
  OPEN raw_cur; 
  LOOP 
    FETCH raw_cur INTO raw_rec; 
    EXIT WHEN raw_cur%NOTFOUND; 
    INSERT INTO Temp_process(Name ,Sal , Deptno) 
      VALUES(raw_rec.Name, raw_rec.Sal, raw_rec.Deptno); 
  END LOOP; 
  COMMIT; 
  CLOSE raw_cur; 
END;
```

Comment: :How did you determine the sal and deptno for ALLEN ,in the unsorted list ,it is 1600 only ?

Comment: dono some one edited it ... :( ..... now its fine :)

Comment: can you help me with this

Comment: :The unsorted data is in table or the list ?

Comment: it is in a table ....

Answer (score 2):

If you guarantee that the data in you source table will be in this particular order you can write a similar query to achieve desired result:

```
-- sample of data from your question
SQL> with t1(col) as(
  2    select 'Scott'  from dual union all
  3    select '100'    from dual union all
  4    select '10'     from dual union all
  5    select 'Miller' from dual union all
  6    select '200'    from dual union all
  7    select '20'     from dual union all
  8    select 'Mike'   from dual union all
  9    select '300'    from dual union all
 10    select '30'     from dual union all
 11    select 'Allen'  from dual union all
 12    select '400'    from dual union all
 13    select '40'     from dual
 14  ) -- the query
 15  select max(decode(mod(rownum - 1, 3), 0, col)) as name
 16       , max(decode(mod(rownum - 1, 3), 1, col)) as sal
 17       , max(decode(mod(rownum - 1, 3), 2, col)) as depno
 18    from t1
 19    group by trunc((rownum -1)/ 3)
 20  /

NAME   SAL    DEPNO
------ ------ ------
Miller 200    20
Mike   300    30
Allen  400    40
Scott  100    10
```

---

**Addendum**

You do not need a cursor for this (unless it's some kind of special requirement that demands use of cursors). To populate other table with data you simply could use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
insert into temp_process(name, sal, depno)
   select max(decode(mod(rownum - 1, 3), 0, col)) 
        , max(decode(mod(rownum - 1, 3), 1, col)) 
        , max(decode(mod(rownum - 1, 3), 2, col))
     from table_a
     group by trunc((rownum -1)/ 3)
```

Comment: can I get this in procedure (plsql) ?

Comment: @user2159389 `can I get this in procedure (plsql)`. Yes, you can. Please provide more detailed requirements.

Comment: got error: 

    SQL> insert into temp_process(name, sal, depno)
    2     select max(decode(mod(rownum - 1, 3), 0, col))
    3          , max(decode(mod(rownum - 1, 3), 1, col))
    4          , max(decode(mod(rownum - 1, 3), 2, col))
    5       from table_a
    6       group by trunc((rownum -1)/ 3)  ;
        , max(decode(mod(rownum - 1, 3), 2, col))
                                            *
    ERROR at line 4:
    ORA-00904: "COL": invalid identifier`

Comment: @user2159389 Replace `COL` column by the column name of your source table