# I want to covert rows from one table to columns to another table using Procedures(Pl/sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedures

```
table A:

col1
_______________________
jack 
1200
20
peter
2000
10
robert 
300
30
```

to

```
table B :

name   sal   deptno
-----------------------
jack 1200 20
peter 2000 10
robert 300 30
```

here I want this by using procedure parameter. can you please help I tried with it but it is giving errors.

```
create procedure GetDatafromtable_A(V_1 in varchar2)
as
CURSOR rwdatacursor IS select Raw_Data  from table_a where rowid<=3)
T_record rwdatacursor%rowtype;
begin
open rwdatacursor;
loop
fetech rwdatacursor into T_record;
exit when rwdatacursor%NOTFUND;
insert into temp_process;
end loop
close rwdatacursor;
end;
```

This is the codew I have tried but showing lot of errors

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: And show us how to relate the rows.  How do we know that 'jack' is a `name`?  How do we know that 1200 is associated with `jack` and not `peter`?  Remembering that rows in a heap-organized table are inherently unordered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get one column data from one table into another table as different columns in PL/SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716454/how-to-get-one-column-data-from-one-table-into-another-table-as-different-column)

Comment: The given ( how to get one column data from one table into another table as different columns in PL/SQL) is not my question. More over that query doenot answer my ques.

Comment: the answer MUST be a procedure because thats what the instructor wants.  Are you in the same class as [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716454/how-to-get-one-column-data-from-one-table-into-another-table-as-different-column) ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is:

```
PROCEDURE CONVERT_TABLES IS
  CURSOR DATA_CURSOR IS
    SELECT COL1
      FROM TABLE_A;

  row1 DATA_CURSOR%ROWTYPE;
  row2 DATA_CURSOR%ROWTYPE;
  row3 DATA_CURSOR%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN DATA_CURSOR;

  LOOP
    FETCH DATA_CURSOR INTO row1;
    EXIT WHEN DATA_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;

    FETCH DATA_CURSOR INTO row2;
    EXIT WHEN DATA_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;

    FETCH DATA_CURSOR INTO row3;
    EXIT WHEN DATA_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;

    INSERT INTO TABLE_B (NAME, SAL, DEPTNO)
      VALUES (row1.COL1, row2.COL1, row3.COL1);
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE DATA_CURSOR;
END CONVERT_TABLES;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I like your solution. But how do we know the data is in the right order? It could change, ain't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Assuming that each `consecutive three  rows are  name sal and deptno`. May be some complicated logic but try it if it helps you.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(slNo INT IDENTITY(1,1),col1 VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #temp 
SELECT col1 FROM table_A

INSERT INTO table_B(name  , sal ,  deptno)
SELECT name,sal,depno
FROM 
  (  SELECT col1 AS name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS RowNum 
     FROM #temp WHERE slNo % 3 =1) AS T1
  FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT col1 AS sal, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS RowNum 
     FROM #temp WHERE slNo%3=2) AS T2
  ON T2.RowNum = T1.RowNum
  FULL OUTER JOIN 
      (SELECT col1 AS depno, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS RowNum 
       FROM #temp WHERE slNo%3=0) AS T3
  ON T3.RowNum = T2.RowNum
  )
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

Comment: I want a procedure query !

Comment: give some time am working on that :) before that just gave you a hint :)

Comment: ok bro here is my thought

create procedurep1(v1 in varchar2)
here v1 is a parameter which we pass into procedure
that parameter i can pass anything
i wan
suppose i pass
'Nithesh,100,2000'
its a parameter
single parameter
with in quotes
that parameter has to splited and placed into different column on the table

Comment: 3 column is fixed right? and 3 rows are sequentially in col1? i mean we can group first 3 so that first one is name second is sal and third is depno. in all group of 3

Comment: As @JustinCave pointed out in his comment on the question, this table is unordered and thus you can't count on getting the rows back in any particular sequence.  The database can return rows in any order it cares to unless an ORDER BY is given.  As this table has no key on which to order the data any query written against it which counts on one row being returned before or after another is inherently unstable, and what "works" today may very well not work tomorrow.  Share and enjoy.